# Количество уникальных строк в большом файле

Tags: c++, алгоритм, память, хеширование

Как посчитать приблизительное количество уникальных строк в файле, используя малое количество памяти (<< количества уникальных строк)? При этом погрешность ответа должна быть не больше нескольких процентов.

Строки приходят "онлайн", т.е. в любой момент требуется сказать текущее примерное количество уникальных. Длина строк может быть различной, но не превосходит маленького числа.

Comment: Какое-то хеширование?...

Comment: @Harry какое?...

Comment: Определяется задачей. Если различных строк порядка 200, то и байта хватит. Наверное... Задача по сути в том, чтоб обеспечить число коллизий на уровне "*не больше нескольких процентов*", а это уже своя теоретическая задача. И вопрос еще и в том, какая именно память "малая", если у вас "длина строк не превосходит маленького числа". Со строками из 2 символов и возиться с хешированием не нужно, грубо говоря. Словом, мне кажется, что условия требуется уточнить.

Comment: @Harry строк <= 5'000'000, уникальных <= 10%, строки <= 10 символов, память должна быть <= 1мб

Comment: Если уникальных так мало, то со сжатием наверное можно и в 1 мб запихнуть. Если результат не обязательно должен быть точным, то можно фильтр блума попробовать

Comment: @user7860670 каким сжатием? 500'000 уникальных это уже в районе 5мб, если 10 байтов на строку

Comment: Эксперимент показывает, что обычного хеширования в 32 бита для строки из VC++ вполне хватает(погрешность до 0.007%). 16 битов мало - погрешность слишком велика. Ну, а примерно 500000 4-байтных значений дадут 2 мегабайта. Это устроит? Если ограничиться 3 байтами (1.5 мегабайта), погрешность будет до 1.5%.

Comment: Ссылка на эксперимент - https://gitlab.com/disputant/rustackoverflow/-/blob/master/exper/hash_1146500.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы просто не прокурутить std::hash по каждой стркое и посчитать их в std::map ?

Если кейс: a b b c d - 3 уникальных - то используем std::map

```
#include <cstdlib>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

int main () {
  
  std::string inFile{"data"};
  std::ifstream input(inFile , std::ios::in);
  if (!input.is_open()) {
    std::cerr << "Error open file : " << inFile << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  
  std::map<std::size_t, std::size_t> m;
  std::hash<std::string> hf{};
  for(std::string line; std::getline(input, line ); ) {
    m[hf(line)] += 1;
  }

  std::size_t ret{0};
  auto fobj{[&ret](std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> v){if (v.second == 1) ++ret;}};
  std::for_each(std::begin(m), std::end(m), fobj);

  std::cout << "Uniq lines : " << ret << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;;
}
```

UPD :
Если кейс: a b b c d - 4 уникальных - то используем std::set

```
#include <cstdlib>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

int main () {
  
  std::string inFile{"data"};
  std::ifstream input(inFile , std::ios::in);
  if (!input.is_open()) {
    std::cerr << "Error open file : " << inFile << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  
  std::set<std::size_t> s;
  std::hash<std::string> hf{};
  for(std::string line; std::getline(input, line ); ) {
    s.insert(hf(line));
  }

  std::cout << "Uniq lines : " << s.size() << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;;
}
```

Comment: Чем это отличается от `std::set`, кроме того что в 2 раза больше памяти за счёт счётчика?

Comment: @вася а где тут set? да и зачем он тут? если есть 2 одинаковых значния хеша как это увидеть в сете? я понял что Вы имеете в виду, но боюст мы немного по разному понимаем понятие uniq

Comment: Вы не так поняли задачу. Надо посчитать не количество строк, которые встретились лишь 1 раз, а количество уникальных строк среди всех строк. Например: `a b b c d` - 4 уникальных, а не 3.

Comment: @вася если это так. то Вы правы. Если автор добавит это пояснение в Вопрсо я удалю ответ как ложный. Спасибо

Comment: @вася я добавил второй вариает. Вы это имели в ввиду?

Comment: Да, но памяти много.

Comment: @вася ну давайте представим такой кейс - "$ sort data | uniq | wc -l"  -много памяти?

Comment: *используя малое количество памяти (<< количества уникальных строк)*, а для сортировки (если это обычная загрузка в память и быстрая сортировка) мы загружаем вообще все строки

Comment: @вася ну вот и я про тоже - миним кол-во юник строк надо прикопать......

Comment: В вопросе говорят про приблизительный ответ, а не точный, если вы об этом.

Comment: @вася тогда это вопрос можно отнести к статистике?

Comment: Зависит от решения. Одно из решений может относится к https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_algorithm, например

Comment: @вася спасибо !